# A An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to insert records in ASP.NET to table but I don't know why I am getting this error. Please help me solve this error. Help is appreciated.

This is the screenshot of table:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

This is the error code I am getting:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

This is Exceptional error image:

[![2][2]][2]

Comment: Isn't there an exception _message_ that tells you more exactly what went wrong?

Comment: is Id column is auto incremented or just a int and not null ?

Comment: id is just int, and I have uploaded a screenshot of error please check it

Comment: No you have not. In that second window, please click on "View Detail.." and copy the _message_ that describes the error.

Comment: `Table` is an SQL reserved word. Change your table name to something not reserved or, if you have to use it, quote it by putting it in brackets like `[Table]`.

Comment: If `id` is no auto-incremented column, you have to specify the `id`, because it must not be `NULL`.

Comment: this is what it shows when I click on view details of Exception error {"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'."}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your query:

1. `Table` is a *keyword* in SQL, so you cannot use it in that way. Either rename the table and give a name that is no keyword in SQL or escape the name in brackets:

   ```
   INSERT INTO [Table]...
   ```

   Obviously, that is what the exception message tells you.
2. If your `id` column is not auto-incremented, you need to pass a value for this column, too, because it must not be `NULL` as your table declaration shows.

Comment: Table is an SQL reserved word. Change your table name to something not reserved or, if you have to use it, quote it by putting it in brackets like [Table].

Answer (score -1):

Try to rename the table name. Also, you can put a breakpoint after you're setting the cmd object to see how the insert statement looks.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into TableName values(@username)",con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Username.Text);
```